# Site not loading below Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have this site that needs to be working in all versions of Internet Explorer from 7 onwards. The issue is when i emulated the site on ie 11 and noticed that it works fine on version 10 and 9 but it gives me an issue on ie 8 and below. I have included respond.js, html5shiv.js and css3-mediaqueries_src.js. But it still doesn't work. I will include my head content for your verification.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="simple.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:801px)" href="complex.css" title="complex layout" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script:700|Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/css3-mediaqueries_src.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/css3-mediaqueries_src.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
       .readonly{
        width: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
       }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: try meta tag : `<meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gt IE 8]>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <![endif]-->        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in head section

Comment: hey ankur, I have editted my code for your verification, it is still not making any difference.

Comment: Please elaborate as what issue you are facing in IE8 & below

Comment: it is not loading col-md-6, it is loading as col-md-12 and the submit button cannot be seen, also the datepicker stops working below ie8

Comment: which version of bootstrap.css & jQuery.js are you using ?

Comment: bootstrap is v3.2.0 and jquery is v1.9.1, i got the jquery to work. The issue was with the commas. However the bootstrap is still causing me problems.

Comment: check the Bootstrap. Browser and device support http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: I have checked that Kishore, I have removed the cdn links from the header and incorporated them in files. I am also testing on the live site.

Comment: What is in the flexslider css?
Using Css reset?

Comment: sorry Damiano, i didn't get you there